# C switch not recognising string

Tags: c, switch-statement

I am trying to take a user input in the form of a string and then use that in a switch, but it always ends up using the default case and not the case for the string I inputted. For the purpose of testing I am inputting just the letter y into this:

```
  char thing[1];
  scanf("%s",thing);
  switch(thing){
    case 'y' :
      printf("yup\n");
      break;
    default :
      printf("nope\n");
  }
```

Comment: What is the return value of scanf()?

Comment: `'y'` and `"y"` are not the same thing. You'll need to use `strcmp` anyway

Comment: You need to switch on `thing[0]` or else just use a normal `char` and not an array

Comment: If you really want to input a string, `char thing[1];` will not be long enough. Strings in C (as implemented by the C standard library functions) are null-terminated, and a `char` array of length 1 is only long enough to hold a zero-length, null-terminated string.

Comment: so if I want a single character string then would I would need it to be char thing[2]; ?

Comment: Yes, a single character string needs a `\0` at the end (2 elements)

Comment: Save time: enable compiler all warnings which should have warned about `switch(thing)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This char array has one element. Your code is crying for a `char` here. You will do fine with a `char` and then get input and check it. Also here in `switch` you have used an pointer value which didn't match with the `char` like `y` etc . Went to default.

```
char thing;
if(scanf("%c",&thing) != 1){
   // error
}
..
```

If you want to use `strcmp` beware that you need to have null terminated char array.

```
char thing[3];
if(scanf("%2s",thing)!= 1){
  // error
}

if(strcmp(thing,"y") == 0){
  printf("yup\n");
}
else{
  printf("nope\n");
}
```

Also you could have done this with your code - but that is not helpful given that you can't use it as `null terminated char array` or string which many of the standard string processing function demands.

```
char thing[1];
if(scanf("%c",&thing[0]) != 1){
   // error
}
switch(thing[0]){
  case 'y' :
    printf("yup\n");
    break;
  default :
    printf("nope\n");
}
```

Comment: @hexidian.: Please read the last block - you will see I have mentioned this is not a string - it is just a char array - we can't use this in string functions.

Comment: Minor point about "can't use this in string functions".  `strn...()` functions can handle  `char` arrays to some degree.   `strncpy(thing, "abc", 1);` is OK - even if foolish.

Comment: @chux.: My hard word should be a little less tight so that the statement covers functions like `strncpy`. Yes you are right this would work ..in fact more genrally any `blahnblah` function would work with this.